# PHP- How to get URL on user click in iFrame showing another website

Tags: php, mysql

I am using an iFrame in my application, in which another website is shown (BBC News). On my website users can login. After a user logs in I want to track all the URLs that specific user visits in the iframe and then store these urls into a MySQL database.

Comment: please post what have you tried

Comment: currently i'm just wondering that is their any mechanism through which I can do that ? So that I can have a look on it

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the BBC, I'm assuming this iframe is loading cross domain therefore it is not possible (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You can however detect the mouse entering the iframe, and unreliably, leaving it.

A way around this would be to proxy the content of the iframe locally from your server. From there you can insert some sort of tracking code or use a function similar to `top.parentFunction();` which returns a reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.

Comment: yes it would be cross domain. Can CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) help me in any way ?